# Unable to mount azure data lake in databricks using secret-scope

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake

I am unable to mount datalake storage using secret-scope.

In the below script I have scrambled applicationID and tenantID for your reference. However, I am getting it from app registration. I have given azure blob contributor to service principal in azure blob storage.

Can anyone please help what is causing the problem? I am receiving NullPointerException

[image]

```
adlsAccountName = "adfsourcefileaccount"
adlsContainerName = "databricks"

mountPoint = "/mnt/{0}/{1}".format(adlsAccountName, adlsContainerName)

applicationId = "xxx"

tenantId = "yyy"

secret_scope = "create-mount"

secret_key = "adfsourcefileaccount"

authenticationKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = secret_scope, key = secret_key)

endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+ tenantId + "/oauth2/token"

source = "abfss://" + adlsContainerName + "@" + adlsAccountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net/"

configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": applicationId,
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret":authenticationKey,
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint":endpoint}

if (any(mount.mountPoint == mountPoint for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts())):

    dbutils.fs.ls(mountPoint)

    print(mountPoint + "already exists")
else:

    mountstatus = dbutils.fs.mount(
        source = source,
        mount_point = mountPoint,
        extra_configs = configs
    )

    print(mountPoint + " : mount point is created and status is " + str(mountstatus))
```

Comment: where yoy are getting error

Comment: Can you provide full error stack?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using correct service principal application ID and client secret. The values you are extracting from Scope in databricks are correct and accessible also make sure your storage account dose not have any firewall rule.

[image]

After this you can use below code to authenticate and create a mount point check if you missed anything.

```py
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<application-id>",
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope-name>",key="<service-credential-key-name>"),
          "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token"}

# Optionally, you can add <directory-name> to the source URI of your mount point.
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

I tried the same with your code and getting succeded

[image]

Reference: [Mounting cloud object storage on Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dbfs/mounts),
[Access storage with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/storage/aad-storage-service-principal)